# Website Display in Directory listing

Tags: wordpress, profile

I have a front end directory which lists websites. When the results are displayed we get the website type (i.e. work, main, etc.) displaying in parenthesis. We want to take that out. For example:

Current display: http://www.website.org (main)

We are looking for it to look like this: http://www.website.org

running CiviCRM 4.6.10 in WordPress.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this easily.  In Profiles, go to the website field and edit the Display field.  The default setting displays the type, but you can easily remove it.

Comment: I do not see that this solution actually works.