# Disabling Web Site type label (work)

Tags: custom-fields, profile, directory

wondering if someone could assist with this naggging issue (small thing that we've spent 4 hours attempting to figure out).

In civi, there are options for phone types, website types etc, and similar the quetion asked in [Website Display in Directory listing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8309/website-display-in-directory-listing)

we are wondering : how the heck do we disable (work) the label for the web site 'type" in parentheses??

Know we've done this before but can;t for the life of us remember how (?)

Going to profile > then the field > as suggested by the ticket above does not give is that option.

Any assistance appreciated!!

D

Answer (score 1):

It is a 'dropdown option' which you can find via Admin > Customise > Dropdown options, or via Admin > System Settings > Option groups

eg

http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/options/website_type?reset=1

Comment: Ok, we see the option to disable the type at https://site.org/civicrm/admin/options/website_type?group=website_type&action=update&id=310&reset=1

Comment: Hi Peter, disabling the web site work type at https://site.org/civicrm/admin/options/website_type?group=website_type&action=update&id=310&reset=1 makes the label diappear but then the type is no longer available to designate the site as "work" type within civi at all. Anyway to just remove the label from the profile listing? Removing the text from the data field in the profile , https://site.org/civicrm/admin/uf/group/field/update?reset=1&action=update&id=100&gid=13 doesn't seem to do it, just removes the header. D

Comment: sorry. i didn't read slow enough to see this was just for a Profile display of the field rather than the DB itself. You would probably need to apply a bit of js to the form to make that option not show.